# jUnit testing Double.toString in multiple cultures

Tags: java, internationalization, junit

I have an open source library which has plenty of unit tests that compare string forms of numbers.

These tests pass fine in `en-GB`, `en-US` and other cultures where numbers are generally written in the form `1,234.00`.

However in cultures such as Germany and France, these values are formatted differently, and the tests fail.

How can the jUnit tests be forced to run as `en-GB`?

**EDIT** [this kind of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991595/nunit-testing-against-multiple-cultures) is available in NUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it's standard for all JVMs, but using Oracle's JVM on Windows, you can use the user.language and user.country System properties to set the locale when starting the JVM:

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=GB ...
```

You can also, of course, set the default locale in Java, using

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "GB"));
```

Note that `Double.toString` is locale-independent, though.

Comment: I had to use the second approach, as I can't control the JVM of developers running tests from my library through their IDEs (for example).  However I'm concerned that after calling this, the locale will remain set as en-GB for other tests too, potentially making tests from other code bases fail.  Do you know of a way to limit the time over which this locale applies, without having to call getLocale/setLocale in @Before/@After methods?

Answer (score 1):

How do you launch jUnit?

Passing the appropriate language property will depend more of your environment than of jUnit itself.

Alternatively (and I think it's a better solution), you could compare values rather than strings:

```
assertEquals(12.3, Double.valueOf(aDoubleString));
assertEquals(Double.toString(12.3), aDoubleString);
```

rather than

```
assertEquals("12.3", aDoubleString)
```

Comment: this is an open source library, so I cannot control how others launch jUnit.  Your idea is an interesting one, but isn't the parsing of strings into doubles also governed by culture-specific rules?

Comment: That's the point. "12.3" might be "12,3" in France. But while assertEquals("12.3", "12,3") would fail hopefully valueOf (or some other NumberFormat local-friendly parsing method) would interpret the value correctly.

Comment: I was referring to `Double.valueOf`, and whether it would treat `"1.234"` and `"1,234"` as the same value irrespective of locale.  My guess is that it cannot, and so the problem shifts from the locale of formatting to the locale of parsing.  I will keep this in mind when I address the problem, so thanks again for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

there are two gists with JUnit 4 rules to modify the default locale for a couple of tests:

[LocaleRule](https://gist.github.com/rponte/5289883), a very simple implementation.

[DefaultLocaleRule](https://gist.github.com/digulla/5884162) has some static helper methods and allows to switch the default locale for an individual test.