# Running NUnit 3 tests under multiple cultures

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, nunit-3.0

Much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991595/nunit-testing-against-multiple-cultures) I have a need to run all my NUnit tests in different cultures. I was hoping that there would be an attribute that allows me to specify cultures and the tests would be run in each culture in turn.

It seems there is a documented attribute detailed [here](https://docs.nunit.org/2.4.7/setCulture.html) which allows you to set the culture that an NUnit test runs under, however it does not allow the setting of multiple cultures.

In the answer to the linked question and several other resources found (such as [here](https://docs.nunit.org/2.4.7/setCulture.html) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/1093505)) which relate to NUnit 2, this feature was a planned improvement for NUnit 3.

As I cannot find evidence that this was implemented, can anyone answer this question please...

**Is there a way to take an existing suite of NUnit 3 test cases and automatically run them in more than one culture in a tidy format?**

I imagine I could write an application script that runs them outside of the IDE but that adds extra overhead.

I also don't relish the idea of  copying and pasting the tests simply changing the "SetCulture" attribute each time (in the same vain I dont want to have to manually change this on an existing fixture before each run)

Comment: It is [present](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/setculture.html) in the documentation that "covers NUnit 3.0 and higher".

Comment: Yes I saw that attribute however the question relates to the statement "Only one culture may be specified. Running a test under multiple cultures is a planned future enhancement." which is a statement I have seen relating to NUnit 2 so Im asking if it has yet been actioned or if there is a decent workaround

Comment: As the documentation says: "At this time, you can achieve the same result by factoring out your test code into a private method that is called by each individual test method."

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing currently built-in to NUnit to do this that I'm aware of, although it's an idea that's been floated a couple of times. (e.g. introducing a `--set-culture` flag for the console runner.)

As a workaround, the SetCulture attribute can be applied at assembly level - so you could potentially have two different assembly-level SetCulture attributes under compilation symbols, and then build your test assembly twice - once for each culture. e.g.

```
#if US_CULTURE
[assembly: SetCulture("en-US")]
#elif UK_CULTURE
[assembly: SetCulture("en-GB")]
#endif
```